# Trying to append and print a removed item from a python list

Tags: python-3.x, append

This is my code:

```
my_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
empty_list = []
n = 0
while(n<7):
    k = my_list.pop()
    removed_list = empty_list.append(k)
    print(removed_list)
    ++n
```

But it keeps on throwing an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/py_code/List.py", line 19, in <module>
    k = my_list.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

and when i take  variable 'k' as output it provided all the removed items but again with same error.so why it is not able to append those items in the new list.

Comment: Python is not `C`, `++n` does not increment `n` - you need `n += 1`. Because `n` is never changing your `while` loop never terminates and `my_list` becomes empty. And not surprisingly `pop()` from an empty list is an error. Note: `while my_list:` would be an easier test and would avoid needing an `n` at all.

Comment: @AChampion - Thanks for advice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append method does not return any value but updates existing list.

```
my_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
empty_list = []
n = 0
while(n<7):
    k = my_list.pop()
    print(k)
    empty_list.append(k)
    n +=1
```

use `n += 1` instead of `++n`